# rewind_posts() and displaying 'no results found' info

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm using rewind_posts() function to group the search results according to a post type and display them under relevant tabs. The loop is working just fine but I'm struggling with displaying a `no results found` info.

For example, if I'm searching for a document, I'd like the post to be displayed under `documents` but under `page` and `people` tabs I need to echo `No results`.

```
        <?php
      if ( have_posts() ) { ?>
        <section class="tabs" id="pages">
          <?php while( have_posts() ) { the_post(); ?>
          <?php if ( $post->post_type == 'page' ) { 
           include(locate_template('partials/pages.php', false, false));  ?>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php
        } ?>
        </section>
        <?php
        rewind_posts(); ?>
          <section class="tabs" id="people">
            <?php while( have_posts() ) { the_post(); ?>
            <?php if ( $post->post_type == 'people' ) { 
             include(locate_template('partials/profile.php', false, false));  ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php
          } ?>
          </section>
        <?php
        rewind_posts(); ?>
        <section class="tabs" id="documents">
          <?php while( have_posts() ) { the_post(); ?>
          <?php if ( $post->post_type == 'documents' ) { 
           include(locate_template('partials/document.php', false, false));  ?>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php
        } ?>
        </section>
        <?php
        rewind_posts(); ?>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're doing could be more efficient by using a switch or if/else rather than using the `rewind_posts()`

This should work in one loop, although I can't actually test your code.

```
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<section class="tabs" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->post_type ); ?>">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post(); ?>
    <?php 
     // Determine the post type and load the appropriate template
     switch ( $post->post_type ) {
        case 'page':
        default:
            include( locate_template( 'partials/pages.php', false, false ) );
            break;
        case 'people':
            include( locate_template( 'partials/profile.php', false, false ) );
            break;
        case 'documents':
            include( locate_template( 'partials/document.php', false, false ) );
            break;
        } 
    } // endwhile
    ?>
</section>
<?php else: 
    echo 'No Posts Found';
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Nevertheless, your code does exactly the same thing as mine. I'm getting 'No posts found' only if there is no posts at all among all the post types. I'd like to display this info only under the tabs which have no results.